# NSSearchField calls action twice on clear

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a very simple `NSSearchField` setup. I want whenever user types in a character, if within a small time frame, user types no more inputs, it automatically calls `action`.

I connected `NSSearchField's` `action` from the interface builder to an `IBAction` in some other objects.

Problem I am facing: for some reason, when user clicks the close button or presses escape key to clear the search filed, the `action` gets triggered twice. Does anyone know how to avoid `action` getting called twice on clear?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction) searchingStarts:(id)sender
{
    printf("action is triggered\n");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
    [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
}

@end
```

You can simply drag a `NSSearchField` to storyboard and link its `action` to `searchingStarts`.

Here's my setup: https://github.com/YLiLarry/nssearchfield-bug

Comment: I start to think this is a bug..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use delegate to avoid this happen.

```
- (void)searchFieldDidEndSearching:(NSSearchField *)sender
```

Answer (score 0):

The action is triggered by the button and because the value changes. If the action can't handle being called multiple times, set the delegate of the search field and implement `NSSearchFieldDelegate` methods

```
- (void)searchFieldDidStartSearching:(NSSearchField *)sender;
```

and

```
- (void)searchFieldDidEndSearching:(NSSearchField *)sender;
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version that worked for me:

Implement NSSearchFieldDelegate methods in your class:

```
extension MyClassName: NSSearchFieldDelegate {

    func searchFieldDidStartSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {
        disableFilter = false
    }

    func searchFieldDidEndSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {
        disableFilter = false
        // TODO: perform cleanup operations if necessary...
    }
}
```

Add *disableFilter* as a variable to your class:

```
class MyClassName: ViewController  {
...
/**
 Used to determine if the cancel button of the NSSearchField was pressed and 
 take steps to avoid the NSSearchField from sending action messages.
*/
var disableFilter: Bool = false
...
}
```

Create the search function:

```
@objc 
func search(_ sender: Any) {
    if disableFilter {
        return
    }

    // TODO: add your search implementation here...
}
```

Assign an action to the search field object, if done in IB ignore this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    searchField.action = #selector(search(_:))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formula in a gentleman's language, for a case where my document view controller actually dispatches to child view controllers—I have a modular window constructions consisting of many tabs and split view containers.

```
@implementation MyDocViewController(search)
#pragma mark - NSSearchFieldDelegate

- (void) searchFieldDidStartSearching: (NSSearchField*) sender
{
    for (NSViewController* aController in self.childViewControllers)
    {
        if ([aController conformsToProtocol: @protocol(NSSearchFieldDelegate)])
        {
            [(NSViewController<NSSearchFieldDelegate>*) aController searchFieldDidStartSearching: sender];
        }
    }
}

- (void) searchFieldDidEndSearching: (NSSearchField*) sender
{
     for (NSViewController* aController in self.childViewControllers)
    {
        if ([aController conformsToProtocol: @protocol(NSSearchFieldDelegate)])
        {
            [(NSViewController<NSSearchFieldDelegate>*) aController searchFieldDidEndSearching: sender];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

In the storyboard, the search field delegate is linked to the above document view controller. There's no direct storyboard access to the sub components assembled in the window and this is why I dispatch to the child view controllers.

In one of the child controller, there will be the same protocol declarations and there will be a final search operation being done. **Note** that this works if only one child view controller actually sets itself as the target of the search field.

```
@implementation MyChildViewController(search)
#pragma mark - NSSearchFieldDelegate

- (IBAction) onSearch: (NSSearchField*) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Filtering on %@", sender.stringValue);

    [self rebuildNodes: sender.stringValue];
}

- (void) searchFieldDidStartSearching: (NSSearchField*) sender
{
    [sender setTarget: self];
    [sender setAction: @selector(onSearch:)];
    [self rebuildNodes: sender.stringValue];
}

- (void) searchFieldDidEndSearching: (NSSearchField*) sender
{
    [sender setTarget: nil];
    [sender setAction: nil];
    [self rebuildNodes: nil];
}
@end
```

@end

In my case, searches are wicked fast. In a CoreData -based object storage document structure, a search completes into a drawn graph highlighting objects in milliseconds, so I can actually search on-the-fly and reset as user enters new search terms.

If you have lengthy search cycles, it might be a good idea to invalidate a previous search timer when you receive new search terms and fire up a new timer (say 1sec) allowing the user to complete a meaningful search term before firing up.

[image: Storyboard Settings]